# The physics/math behind rogue waves

Tags: fluid-dynamics, oceanography

I'm a little confused as to why [rogue waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_wave) are so unpredictable and large. Are they just the chance combinations of many waves or is there a physical and mathematical reasoning as to how they exist? If so, can they be predicted?

Comment: [Loooong story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_wave#Causes) of incertitude.

Comment: There was an article in APSNews of January. http://www.aps.org/publications/apsnews/201801/history.cfm  
"In 2016, MIT scientists devised a new algorithmic prediction tool to spot clusters of waves in the ocean that could develop into a massive rogue wave, giving sailors a few minutes warning before the wave hits."